# How can I get Raspbian Lite to support TrueColor, or change default terminal away from LXTerminal?

Tags: raspbian-lite

I have Raspbian Lite installed, which defaults to LXTerminal.

This states that LXTerminal supports truecolor if I can run it with a flag https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728 `--enable-gtk3`

I was hoping just using `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` would work, but regardless of what I choose it still boots into LXTerminal

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion here: Raspbian lite is the headless version which comes with no GUI, and by default boots to a *[virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console)*.  LXTerminal is a GUI app that requires an X server.  That and the VC are not the same thing.

> So is my only option here to install a GUI and then run a terminal emulator in full screen mode?

If you want features particular to a GUI terminal (such as true color), I think so.  Although the [framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer), which supports true color, is available, there are not many apps that actually use it.  This does include at least one terminal emulator,<sup>1</sup> [`fbterm`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fbterm) (that's Arch wiki documentation but it is the same software on Raspbian), but I do not think it is widely used (and having glanced at it, I don't recommend it).

---

1. All these things are called "virtual" and/or "emulator", including the bare bones VC, for way-back historical reasons (ie., you will probably never see a "real console").